# Default parameters in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a function, for example

**function test(p1:int=7,p2:Boolean=true,p3:uint=0xffff00,p4:Number=55.5)
{

    //instructions

}**

How to change **only p4**, for example, and parameters p1,p3,p3 **was still default**?
Next time I want to change for example **only p2**, and parameters p1,p3,p4 **was still default**?
etc.

Answer (score 2):

you could always do something like (but I don't think it's a great idea):

```
private function test(a1:Object=null, a2:Object=null, a3:Object = null, a4:Object = null):void {
    var p1:int      = (a1 !== null ? int(a1) : 3);
    var p2:Boolean  = (a2 !== null ? Boolean(a2) : true);
    var p3:uint     = (a3 !== null ? uint(a3) : 0xFFFF00);
    var p4:Number   = (a4 !== null ? Number(a4) : 55.5);
}
```

that way if you want something to be default, you can just pass in null:

with:

```
test(null,false,null,null);
```

but again, it's a bad idea.  Maybe make the parameter an object -- it sounds like you're passing in a colortransform object -- which already has rgb + alpha + transparency?  (just a wild guess)

Comment: It's very good idea. All is OK. 
I replaced in function class :void to :Array and in function wrote line
return [p1,p2,p3,p4];
Next call function trace(test(null,false,null,125));
All is super.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can leave p3 and p4 out and they will use the default value when you want to only specify p2. But then you'd have to enter a value for p1 too.